# UPI Intent flow options not showing in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15

I have integrated payment gateway. From iOS 15 the UPI intent apps flow options are not showing in my application but they are working in devices below iOS 15. Any idea what could be the reason. Any new update came in iOS 15 which is restricting the use of Intent apps.?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you have implemented payment gateway they will not accept your app while review. I have tried to uploaded app and they rejected it saying third party payment integration are not allowed. So I suggest you to use in-App purchase.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Bhavik..but we can add third party payment gateways in our app..Also my issue got resolved. As in iOS 15 if you want to load anything on WebView you have to call webviewdidfinish method and inside this perform your loading. This will work.